# How to implement in-app purchase for unmanaged/non-consumable products using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I'm using the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase), a flutter plugin to implement product consumables.

When I try to consume the product again,  I get the following message.

> "you already own this item"

Is there a way to implement in-app purchases for unmanaged/non-consumable products in the app?

Comment: Please add your code to get faster response.